# If a finite group acts transitively on a set, does its center also acts transitively?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> If $G$ is a finite group acts transitively on a set $X$, does the center $Z(G)$ also acts on $X$ transitively?

I don't see how this statement will be true but I can't come up with a counter example either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since the center can certainly be trivial, of course no!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Think about the Symmetric group $S_3$ acting on $\{1,2,3\}$. What is the center of $S_3$? In fact, any $S_n$ for $n > 2$ acting on $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ will work. Why?